# KernelObject appears dead problem

Tags: parallelization

my cluster got 24 cores

And I use this setting to do parallel computing

```
    CloseKernels[]
    LaunchKernels[6]
    ParallelEvaluate@SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions"->"MKLThreadNumber"->4];
    ParallelDo[...some Eigenvalue calculation....]
```

I use

```
nohup math -run "<<job.m" > nohup2.out 2>&1 &
```

and in the output of `nohup2.out`, I often see this error message

> LinkObject::linkd:     Unable to communicate with closed link 
>       LinkObject["/fs10/home/m103/Executables/wolfram" -subkernel
>         -noinit -wstp, 97, 6].
>
> Kernels::rdead:     Subkernel connected through KernelObject[6, local]
>   appears dead.
>
> Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::req:     Requeueing evaluations {1}
>   assigned to KernelObject[6, local, ].
>
> LaunchKernels::clone:     Kernel KernelObject[6, local, ]
>   resurrected as 
>       KernelObject[7, local].

What does it mean? Sometimes I got it, sometimes not. While the calculation goes on in spite of the message, will this affect my calculation?

Comment: Hard to say without the code, but this does sound like a bug fixed in version 10.4.1.

Comment: @ilian I use 10.3 on my cluster. So this is a bug? Under what conditions will it occur? I just ran 3 tasks on three different nodes, only one got this problem

Comment: I used to observe this warning when doing some... heavy parallel computing with v8.0.4, not sure about the exact reason also.

Comment: @xzczd Hi, xzczd. I am worried whether the result will be right or not when seeing such a message

Comment: You still got an answer after these warning? In my case MMA didn't return an answer for several days so I finally quit the kernel.

Comment: @xzczd I am not sure whether MMA will gives me an answer finally, but the nohup2.out is still updating screen output of iteration step information